# constructor methods in interfaces

Tags: php, oop

Are constructor methods in interfaces bad?

Comment: Since you can't instantiate an interface how would you even use it?

Comment: I mean specifying a constructor in an interface.

Comment: Removed the subjective tag.  There doesn't seem to be anything subjective about this question.

Comment: "I mean specifying a constructor in an interface."-We know what you mean ... at least I think we do.  What you need to do is figure out a scenario where you might want to use it.  I think you will find that none make sense.  But if you do find one that makes sense, it'd be a good opportunity to teach us all something.  Good luck.

Comment: This question is not tagged with a language. Choice of language may affect the answers to this question.

Comment: @veefu, I agree but I'm struggling to think of a language which 1) has actual support for interfaces and 2) supports a constructor on such type.

Comment: added PHP tag. Supports constructor in interface.
Use case: a user object that needs a session object for it to work. The constructor in the interface tells the program: if you want to create me you need to construct me with a session object as constructor argument.

Answer (score 41):

Why do people think that anybody wants to instantiate the interface?

What we want to do is to force implementers to implement the constructor, just like other interface methods.

An interface is like a contract. Let's say I have an interface Queue, and I want to make sure that implementers create a constructor with one argument, which creates a singleton queue (A new queue with just that element). Why should that not be part of the contract? With at least Java interfaces, that cannot be specified.

Comment: +1 So, no, they're not bad. `Why do people think that anybody wants to instantiate the interface?` Agreed, IMO the OP wasn't asking that. If a class requires a value each time it's instantiated (say, a wrapper class) it seems to me that a data passing contract can be useful. Particularly in PHP where methods can't be overridden - the constructor is "locked in" to a certain behavior.

Comment: Methods can be overridden in PHP but not overloaded.

Comment: Perhaps @Steve was referring to the obligation to match the constructor's signature.

Comment: If you want to arbitrarily enforce implementations of an interface to specify n constructor parameters, you're doing OOP wrong. In the case of static methods you'll never have an object to resolve the type from, i.e. polymorphism does not apply to static methods. Constructors are static methods. Clients of a Queue type might want to call `add` or `get`. However, these clients will never call the constructor and as such interfaces should not specify the constructor method. Being able to specify a `__construct` in an interface is a good example of how PHP was just created rather than designed.

Answer (score 12):

They are bad in that they serve no purpose.  At its core, an interface is simply a data passing contract.  There is no implemenation attached with an interface and hence there is nothing to initialize and no need for a constructor.

If you need some sort of initialization your much better off using an abstract class.

Comment: Btw, I think, interface is more than "simply data passing contract". It should be thought as responsibility contract which in turn includes signature specification.

Comment: @isntn, at it's core all an interface does is specify how to pass data. The only think that guarantees behavior are contracts and test frameworks.  Interfaces can imply behavior but they cannot guarantee it

Comment: I agree with JaredPar. If you have the constructor in your interface, it seems that you need an abstract Class. You will get some common behaviour for the components implementing this interface, at least for setter/getter methods related to the variables passed to the __construct method, so you should go, IMO, to an abstract class in this context.

Comment: The solution of using an abstract class depends on the context - whether or not you want (or can) limit the implementors so that they must inherit from a specific class. PHP is a single-inheritance language, so this restriction might or might not be acceptable under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

First off, I disagree that interface is just a data passing contract. If that were true you would be allowed to define properties in an interface.

I wouldn't exactly think it's weird to do something like:

```
interface IDBConnection
{
    function __construct( $connectionString );
    function executeNonQuery( $commandText, $paramters=null);
    function executeScalar( $commandText, $paramters=null);
    function executeSingle( $commandText, $paramters=null);
    function executeArray( $commandText, $paramters=null);
}
```

This would enable you to create instances of third party classes for data access based on simple reflection instead of just being a data contract.

I'm pretty sure that this isn't the best example, I'd go for an abstract base class here in the real world, but I'm also pretty sure that there are perfectly valid reasons for defining a constructor methods' contract in an interface that I haven't thought of.

I haven't seen it done, but i wouldn't think it to be weird or bad.

Answer (score 4):

Although interfaces can't have constructors in most languages, the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) provides a contract for constructing objects, similar to an interface. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not they are bad, I am not aware of any language that has the ability to specify a constructor on an interface.

That being said, however, I personally do not believe that the constructor of an object is part of that object's interface and as such adding a constructor to an interface would inhibit the natural flexibility that interfaces afford.

Comment: It's late, but PHP has this ability. (This doesn't make it a feature worth having, but that's only my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate immutable polymorphic objects sometime via their constructor that requires parameters and you may need that constructor in the interface for the exact same reasons you may need the other public methods in the interface, for example…

Say you have to instantiate a polymorphic object, its class implementing your interface and being supplied by the client code. As a dumb but simple scenario let's say this object is a value object and as such should be immutable, which mean the object's state should be valid from the moment it's instantiated…

```
$immutablePolymorphe = $userConfig['immutable_polymorphe_class'];
$immutablePolymorphe = new $immutablePolymorphe($state);
// Then do something with that polymorphe...
```

So what if you don't define the constructor with its parameter in the interface? Hence the reason why I believe a constructor in an interface can be as much legitimate as any other public method in an interface…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Google sent me here :)

But the question is an interesting one, and I have seen some people in many projects defining the constructor in the interface. But I really think it is a useless restriction. No client of this class can call `__construct`.

And defining it in the interface does not restrict any behavior, still I can implement it as I wish, I can even have an empty function like:

```
...
function __construct(string $name) {}
...
```

Then what is the benefit from it? It just blocks you from doing polymorphism, without any single benefit.

So if you have:

```
<?php
interface Shape {
   function __construct(int $width, int $height);
   public function getArea();
}

class Square implements Shape {
   public function __construct(int $width, int $height) {...}
   public function getArea(){...}
}

// This will throw an exception because it does not implement the correct constructor signature!
class Circle implements Shape {
   public function __construct($radius) {...}
   public function getArea(){...}
}
```

And even if you want to extend Square, then you have to implement the same constructor!.

And there is an example in the answers like:

> You have to instantiate immutable polymorphic objects...

and example looks like:

```
$immutablePolymorphe = $userConfig['immutable_polymorphe_class'];
$immutablePolymorphe = new $immutablePolymorphe($state);
// Then do something with that polymorphe...
```

That is smart thinking, but only if you can restrict the strings in the `$userConfig` array to be of a specific interface! Which is not possible at least to my knowledge.

So bottom line :D I think having `__construct` in the interface is bad and blocks you from evolving your software, and it encourages you to have bad workarounds.